# Создание своего редактора UML диаграмм

Tags: android

Всем привет. Передо мной стоит задача, создания редактора, чем то похожего на редактор UML диаграмм. То есть, есть блоки (иконки) с надписями, и между ними можно устанавливать связи, делать ресайз и т.п. Прям, что-то похожего или как это можно реализовать на просторах интернета я не нашел. Предполагаю, что можно это сделать через SurfaceView или какой-нибудь движок типа unity. Может кто-то сталкивался с подобным и поделится своими соображениями по этому поводу? Буду признателен любым советам в этом направлении.

Comment: Здравствуйте! Также занят этой задачей, диплом такой. Если ещё актуально, отпишитесь, как успехи у Вас.

Comment: Есть большое количество JS библиотек, которые такое умеют. Посмотрите в сторону webview и всяких кроссплатформенных движков, его использующих.